# Passing Captivate Parameters

Tags: php, flash, adobe-captivate

I want to track when users have viewed a Captivate (Flash 10.0) video tutorial. In order to do this I need to pass two parameters (employee ID and which tutorial) and have the video call a url with the passed values when it's done. I *think* I can pass the parameters to the turorial when it starts but I'm not sure how to get them back out when the video is done. The end of the video would have a "Completed" button the user would click but I'm not sure how to address the parameters and their values.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do it is to place the parameters in the HTML file's *JavaScript* and NOT in the Captivate file. There's really no reason to pass the params to the Captivate file unless you're using them elsewhere.

If you have the params in JavaScript, at the end of the Captivate video slide you can simply invoke a JavaScript function that handles sending the data to your LMS.

```
var employeeID = "abc123";
var tutorialID = "tutorial_01";

function setTutorialToComplete(){
   var url = "http://www.yoururl.org/index.html?emp=" + employeeID + "&tut=" + tutorialID;
   //use the URL somehow. maybe use ajax to do a post/get using your vars
}
```

In your Captivate file, just invoke setTutorialToComplete() when the video has finished.

Comment: @pipwerks: another user has created an answer which appears to be a question to you.

Answer (score 0):

"Course Companion for Adobe Captivate 5.5" from Adobe Labs is designed to address reporting issues such as this one: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/captivate_course/