# Question From Answer to - "Passing Captivate Parameters"

Tags: adobe-captivate

[Passing Captivate Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092908/passing-captivate-parameters/1644011#1644011)

Can the score quiz be passed still using this method? How can it be passed with the name and employee number? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. *How* you do it depends on which version of Captivate you're using.

Extracting a quiz score from Captivate 3 requires a hack to the 'submit quiz results via email' feature. See this article:
http://pipwerks.com/2008/09/07/send-captivate-quiz-data-to-javascript/

Captivate 4 introduces a new 'system variables' feature that makes it much easier to extract a quiz score. I suggest checking the Adobe Captivate forums for instructions; many people have written about it there.